# Is it possible to use groovy formatter in IntelliJ without opening Editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I want to format groovy style code for using Jenkinsfile.

I could not find good tool to format groovy style, but IntelliJ-IDEA one is good.

I don't want to open IntelliJ-IDEA for formatting Jenkinsfile eveny time.

Is it possible to format intellij's formatter without opening IntelliJ-IDEA?

Comment: Not possible now. There is a request for this: [IDEA-180965](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180965).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can format files from the command line by running `idea.sh format`. You can find more information in the [IntelliJ IDEA help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-formatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **npm-groovy-lint** with `--format` option, it is not IntelliJ formatter but is based on the same linter (CodeNarc), so works pretty well :)

https://github.com/nvuillam/npm-groovy-lint